# 'unexpected character after line character'

Tags: python

I'm working on a code that will print out contents of a text file in python.

everything seems stable so far apart from my last line(s):

```
f2 = open('D:\\1CP0_02_June 2016_Paper - Copy\\paintingJobs.txt','r')
for lineB in f2:
    if "A" in lineB:
        listB = [lineB]
print("Estimate Number\tEstimate Date\tCustomer ID\tFinal Total\tAmount Paid\tAmount Outstanding")
print(listB[0]\tlistB[1]\tlistB[2]\tlistB[3]\tlistB[4]\tlistB[5])
```

The last line creates an error during execution, saying 'unexpected character after line character'

Any tips?

`listB` has the following inside of it (just for clarification):

```
['E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290\n']
['E5344,22/09/2015,C105,180,A,180\n']
['E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400\n']
['E5348,23/09/2015,C109,370,A,200\n']
['E5349,25/09/2015,C110,480,A,250\n']
['E5350,25/09/2015,C111,330,A,330\n']
['E5353,28/09/2015,C114,272,A,200\n']
['E5355,29/09/2015,C116,530,A,450\n']
['E5358,29/09/2015,C119,380,A,380\n']
['E5361,01/10/2015,C122,374,A,374\n']
['E5363,01/10/2015,C124,930,A,500\n']
['E5364,02/10/2015,C125,915,A,800\n']
['E5365,02/10/2015,C126,1486,A,1486\n']
['E5367,03/10/2015,C128,427,A,350\n']
['E5368,05/10/2015,C129,1346,A,1346\n']
['E5371,10/10/2015,C132,289,A,289\n']
['E5373,10/10/2015,C134,1023,A,550\n']
['E5376,13/10/2015,C137,297,A,297\n']
['E5380,15/10/2015,C141,425,A,425']
```

Comment: What is your `listB` and `tlistB`? Probably you have a typo error with your `listB`?

Comment: tlistB doesn't exist, there is '\t' before every listB.

Comment: see the answer and you'll understand your error

Comment: You could try my version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956356/unexpected-character-after-line-character/34956510#34956510

Answer (score 4):

```
print(listB[0]\tlistB[1]\tlistB[2]\tlistB[3]\tlistB[4]\tlistB[5])
```

What's this? It looks like you want to print tab characters, but you can't just stick a tab character somewhere to have it printed, it has to be in a string:

```
print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(*listB[:6])
```

It may be easier to just join the strings, though:

```
print("\t".join(listB))
```

Comment: I think the .join() would throw a TypeError if any element is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this for the last line instead.

```
print(listB[0], "\t", listB[1], "\t",  listB[2], "\t", listB[3], 
      "\t",  listB[4], "\t",  listB[5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer according to the question update:

you don't need to have this data in a list:

```
['E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290\n']
```

it would be better to have it as a string(because it's string in the list, it doesn't have any sense)

So, if you'll have your listB like this one:

```
['E5342,21/09/2015,C103,290,A,290\n', 'E5344,22/09/2015,C105,180,A,180\n', 'E5345,22/09/2015,C106,815,A,400\n', 'E5348,23/09/2015,C109,370,A,200\n', 'E5349,25/09/2015,C110,480,A,250\n', 'E5350,25/09/2015,C111,330,A,330\n', 'E5353,28/09/2015,C114,272,A,200\n']
```

you should print your data in the next way:

```
for item in listB:
    print("Estimate Number: {0}\tEstimate Date: {1}\tCustomer ID: {2}\tFinal Total: {3}\tAmount Paid: {4}\tAmount Outstanding: {5}".format(*item.strip().split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

With your code above, `listB` will only contain the last line from the file because you assign `[lineB]` with every iteration instead of appending it.

Plus, if "A" happens to show up anywhere else than in the fifth field of your string, e.g. in Estimate Number or Customer ID, it will also be included in `listB`, even if Amount Paid is not "A".

How about this?

```
listB = []
with open("d:/filename.txt") as f2:
    for lineB in f2:
        if "A" == lineB.split(',')[4]:
            listB.append(lineB.replace(',','\t').rstrip('\n'))

print("Estimate Number\tEstimate Date\tCustomer ID\tFinal Total\tAmount Paid\tAmount Outstanding")
print("\n".join(listB))
```